# How to get sum of distinct date count for columns in 6 month interval?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregation

I have transaction table which is in user level, I want to aggregate them such as sum of distinct transaction date count for each individual columns per user in 6 month long interval. I used subquery to do this aggregation but not getting right output though.

**minimal table and my attempt** :

```
CREATE TABLE trans (
  user_id varchar(10),
  purchase_date timestamp,
  prod1_amt INT,
  prod2_amt INT,
  prod3_amt INT,
  prod4_amt INT,
  prod5_amt INT,
  prod6_amt INT
);

INSERT INTO trans (user_id, purchase_date, prod1_amt, prod2_amt, prod3_amt, prod4_amt, prod5_amt, prod6_amt)
VALUES (A,1/14/2021,10,6,0,0,11,0)
        ,(A,6/14/2021,10,6,0,0,11,0)
        ,(B,1/14/2021,10,6,0,0,11,0)
        ,(B,11/14/2021,10,6,0,0,11,0)
        ,(C,6/14/2021,10,6,0,0,11,0)
       , (B,1/10/2022,5,18,0,5,11,7)
       ,(A,1/19/2022,6,18,2,5,0,0)
       ,(A,1/19/2022,10,28,1,7,11,7)
       ,(B,1/19/2022,100,18,1,5,11,7)
       ,(C,1/20/2022,25,18,1,5,11,7)
       ,(C,1/20/2022,35,18,1,5,11,7)
       ,(B,4/19/2022,9,18,1,5,11,7)
       ,(A,5/23/2022,10,18,1,0,0,0)
       ,(A,7/23/2022,10,18,1,5,11,7)
       ,(B,7/23/2022,10,18,11,15,11,17)
       ,(C,8/23/2022,10,18,1,5,11,7);
```

**my current query**:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE aggr_output_table(
    WITH trns_base AS (
        SELECT *, 
            EXTRACT(YEAR FROM purch_date) || '_' || 
            CASE 
            WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM purch_date) IN (1, 2) THEN 'h1'
            WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM purch_date) IN (3, 4) THEN 'h2'
            END AS period_dt,
        FROM (
        SELECT *, 
            user_id,
            count(distinct purchase_date) tx_dt
        FROM trans 
        )
    ),
    concat_tbl AS (
        SELECT 
            user_id, 
            concat(period_dt || '_' ||, prod1_amt, prod2_amt, prod3_amt, prod4_amt, prod5_amt, prod6_amt) AS tx_period_metric,
            COUNT(DISTINCT tx_date) cnt
        FROM trns_base
        GROUP BY 1, 2
    )
    select
        base.*,
        ctl.*,
    from trns_base base
    left join concat_tbl ctl on ctl.user_id=base.user_id
)
```

but this query is not giving my expected output though. Can anyone suggest better workaround to get this done? not necessarily to get nice column name that I showed in desired output, but just want to make aggregation right the way I expect.

**objective**:

I just want to get sum of count distinct of transaction date for each individual columns per user in 6 month interval. How can I fix my above sql attempt? Can anyone point me out with better approach?

**update**

I am not quite familiar with dynamic sql, so not expecting dynamic sql here. just getting close enough to my expected output with correct aggregation that I want. dynamic sql is optional so I can learn it also.

**desired output**:

I think what I am gonna do is not very complex, just concatenating corresponding year period and column name is not clear for me how to do it in SQL. here is table schema of expected output table:

```
CREATE TABLE aggr_trans (
    user_id VARCHAR(10),
    2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod1_amt INT,
    2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod1_amt INT,
    2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod1_amt INT,
    2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod1_amt INT,
    
    2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod2_amt INT,
    2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod2_amt INT,
    2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod2_amt INT,
    2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod2_amt INT,
    
    2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod3_amt INT,
    2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod3_amt INT,
    2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod3_amt INT,
    2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod3_amt INT,
    
    2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod4_amt INT,
    2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod4_amt INT,
    2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod4_amt INT,
    2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod4_amt INT,
    
    2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod5_amt INT,
    2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod5_amt INT,
    2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod5_amt INT,
    2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod5_amt INT,
    
    2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod6_amt INT,
    2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod6_amt INT,
    2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod6_amt INT,
    2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod6_amt INT
);
```

how can I get something similar to this expected output in sql?

Comment: Run `SELECT @@version;` to give us server version. Also, `M/DD/YYYY` is not a valid date format for `date` datatype.

Comment: @FanoFN I aware that, if date format is not issue, rest of minimal data should be fine. I am actually using bigquery, but for this test, I am using postgre sql 9.3.

Comment: `int(10)` is not valid for Postgre**s**.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated my post. I am using bigquery for actual problem, but here for this minimal example, I am testing postgre sql or mysql. Could you share any thoughts as an answer?

Comment: Is it right that you consider only the transaction date without paying attention to the actual values of `prod?_amt` columns ?

Comment: And if possible, would you share the expected results for your current input instead of the output table schema ?

Comment: @Jaytiger if getting output table schema would be nice, but concatenating string is gonna become issue I think. I want total unique transaction date for each column in 6 month window

Comment: @Jaytiger instead of exact output table schema that I showed, can do something similar though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but concatenating string is gonna become issue I think. I want total unique transaction date for each column in 6 month window

Below will return the column names in your expected schema as values.

```sql
WITH stacked AS (
  SELECT *, 
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tx_date) || '_' || 
        CASE 
          WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM tx_date) IN (1, 2) THEN 'h1' -- 1st, 2nd Quarter 
          WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM tx_date) IN (3, 4) THEN 'h2' -- 3rd, 4th Quarter
        END AS period_name,
    FROM (
      SELECT *,
             PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', purchase_date) tx_date,
             "trns_cnt_prod" || (offset + 1) || '_amt' AS metric_name
        FROM trans,
      UNNEST ([prod1_amt, prod2_amt, prod3_amt, prod4_amt, prod5_amt, prod6_amt]) WITH offset
    )
)
SELECT user_id, period_name || '_' || metric_name AS period_metric, COUNT(DISTINCT tx_date) cnt
  FROM stacked GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

**Query results**

[image]

You can pivot above result to generate a table with your desired schema:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT user_id, period_name || '_' || metric_name AS period_metric, COUNT(DISTINCT tx_date) cnt
    FROM stacked GROUP BY 1, 2
) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(cnt) FOR period_metric IN (
    '2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod1_amt', '2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod1_amt', '2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod1_amt', '2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod1_amt',
    '2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod2_amt', '2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod2_amt', '2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod2_amt', '2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod2_amt',
    '2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod3_amt', '2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod3_amt', '2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod3_amt', '2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod3_amt',
    '2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod4_amt', '2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod4_amt', '2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod4_amt', '2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod4_amt',
    '2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod5_amt', '2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod5_amt', '2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod5_amt', '2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod5_amt',
    '2021_h1_trns_cnt_prod6_amt', '2021_h2_trns_cnt_prod6_amt', '2022_h1_trns_cnt_prod6_amt', '2022_h2_trns_cnt_prod6_amt'
  ));
```

[image]